# Swift – Table view data not reloading after dismissing view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I have a view in my app called `JournalViewController` that I'm presenting over my `PastSessionsViewController`. `PastSessions` has a table view that the user can tap to edit and bring up the journal.

When the user edits an entry and saves it (saving to CoreData), dismissing `JournalViewController` I'd like for the table view in `PastSessions` to reflect those changes and show the updated table cell.

I'm calling `tableView.reloadData()` in `PastSessionsViewController` `viewDidLoad()` but that doesn't seem to be working. I've also added a delegate for `JournalViewController` to interact with `PastSessionsViewController` ahead of `dismissViewController`

Here's some code to look at:

In `PastSessionsViewController`:

```
class PastSessionsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, JournalVCDelegate {
    weak var tableView: UITableView?
    weak var backButton: UIButton?

    let pastSessionsDataSource: PastSessionsDataSource

    init() {
        pastSessionsDataSource = PastSessionsDataSource()
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.backgroundColor = nil
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = pastSessionsDataSource
        tableView.registerClass(EntryCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        self.tableView = tableView
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        tableView?.reloadData()
    }

    func didFinishJournalVC(controller: JournalViewController) {
        var newDataSource = PastSessionsDataSource()
        tableView?.dataSource = newDataSource
        // tried this ^, but it's causing the app to crash 

        // tableView?.reloadData() <- this isn't doing the trick either
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let editJournalVC = JournalViewController(label: "Edit your thoughts")
        editJournalVC.delegate = self

        presentViewController(editJournalVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

In `JournalViewController`:

```
protocol JournalVCDelegate {
    func didFinishJournalVC(controller: JournalViewController)
}

class JournalViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    var delegate: JournalVCDelegate! = nil

    func doneJournalEntry(sender: UIButton) {
        journalEntryTextArea?.resignFirstResponder()

        ... do some core data saving ...
        delegate.didFinishJournalVC(self)
    }
}
```

In `PastSessionsDataSource`:

```
   import UIKit
   import CoreData

   class PastSessionsDataSource: NSObject {
        var arrayOfEntries = [Entry]()
        var coreDataReturn: [Meditation]?

        func prepareEntries() {
          // gets stuff from coredata and formats it appropriately
        }

        override init() {
            super.init()
            prepareEntries()
        }
    }

    extension PastSessionsDataSource: UITableViewDataSource {
        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return arrayOfEntries.count
        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EntryCell

            ... set up the labels in the cell ...

            return cell
        }
    }
```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: No visible issues in a code above. Also in a sample from viewDidLoad I do not see reloadData called. Did you tried to debug it? Is data loaded from core data properly? Are methods of data source called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently prepare entries only on init of PastSessionsDataSource, but not after you did CoreData changes. So each time when you reloadData for tableView you work with the same data set loaded initially. As a quick hack you can try to updated viewDidAppear in a following way:

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        if let tableView = tableView {
          let dataSource = tableView.dataSource! as PastSessionsDataSource
          dataSource.prepareEntries()
          tableView.reloadData()
        }
 }
```

Comment: I see what you're saying. Unfortunately that didn't work either

Comment: @ZackShapiro what did you get? Compilation error, crash, no content updated? I do not have whole setup so can not run it on my machine.

Comment: @ZackShapiro could you provide details how actually it does not work?

Comment: @ZackShapiro also I am curious does prepareEntries called each time? Could you check this? Because if it is so, the issue is with data, not with rendering of it.

Comment: There's no change to the table view contents after dismissing the `JournalViewController` and viewing `PastSessions`

Comment: @ZackShapiro could you confirm that prepareEntries called each time?

Comment: On it right now, will report back in a few mins using your code above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82151/discussion-between-nikita-leonov-and-zack-shapiro).

Answer (score 2):

`viewDidLoad` is called when the view controller load its view at the first time, so basically it will only be called once during the view controller's whole life cycle.
One quick solution is to put `tableView.reloadData()` in `PastSessionsViewController viewWillAppear() or viewDidAppear()`.
However I do not like this quick solution as every time you dismiss `JournalViewController`, the table view will be reloaded, even the user has not changed anything on `JournalViewController` (for example, cancel the edit). So I suggest to use delegate approach between `PastSessionsViewController` and `JournalViewController`, when the user actually edit the data on `JournalViewController` then inform `PastSessionsViewController` to refresh the table.

Comment: Should I use the delegate to call the PastSessionsDataSource class to update the data? Since that's where CoreData is loading and filling the table view cells? I'm very confused as to how to solve this

Comment: I updated the code above using delegate methods, it's still not working, would you mind taking a look please?

Answer (score 1):

Your `tableView` property is probably `nil` in `viewDidAppear`, based on your listed code. The reason is that in `viewDidLoad` you construct a `UITableView` as `tableView`, and that is a local variable. You need to assign that variable to the property:

`self.tableView = tableView`

Comment: I was code-blind, you are absolutely right with your answer. I think bounty is yours.

Comment: @raheel I updated the code, I'm actually doing that already. I took that out accidentally when I was editing down the contents of `viewDidLoad` to share my code

Comment: @ZackShapiro nice, so I am back in the game :)

Comment: Absolutely :). Go for it